# How to print feedbacks on moodle questions?

Tags: moodle

I create quizzes using the `moodle` package in LaTeX.

```
\begin{multi}[feedback={MY FEEDBACK}]
Problem here 
\item* right choice
\item wrong choice
\end{multi}
```

When it is compiled, I only see the multiple choices but not the feedback.

How can I print the feedback in PDF?

Comment: This seems not supported. Maybe you can ask @mgk here: https://gitlab.mattgk.myds.me/mattguer/moodle/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the moodle.sty file. The new file https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/ will solve the problem.

Comment: The file `moodle.sty` can be generated from `moodle.dtx` and `moodle.ins` using the command `latex moodle.ins`